# R - How to replace a set of values with another set of values

Tags: r, find, replaceall

I have this problem which I can solve manually but I feel there must be an easier answer.
I want to replace  2 with A, 22 with B, 4 with C, ...
I have all the values I want to replace in an array and another [A,B,C,D,...].
Is there an easy way to perform this replacement?
Thanks,
Miguel

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: for(j in 1:647054){
  for(i in 1:38){
  replace(table1$coll[j], table1$coll[j] == distinct_val[i] ,arr_letters[i])
  }
} where distinct_val is the array I want to replace and arr_letters is the array of letters. This takes to long though. I was hoping for a function which could perform this replacement efficiently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data.table`

```
DT[column1 == "2", column1 := "A"]
```

If you want to do a group of them at a time, then use `setkey` from `data.table` and `merge` the dataset with the reference dataset.

```
setkeyv(DT, 'column1')
setkeyv(referenceSet, 'oldVars')

merge(DT, referenceSet, all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use named vectors.

```
x <- sample(1:10, 8)
x
# [1]  4  9  6 10  8  3  7  5
y <- c("A", "B", "C")
names(y) <- 1:3
x[x%in%names(y)] <- y[x[x%in%names(y)]]
x
# [1] "4"  "9"  "6"  "10" "8"  "C"  "7"  "5"
```